# download file from a url that returns a save dialog box

Tags: wget

I have a url which on clicking returns a save dialog box for a pdf file. I would like to save this file using wget. Any ideas how to do this?

Basically the url is not the url of a file but a server function call that returns the file by promoting the user with open/save dialog box.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to use `wget` and you're trying to do it with the mouse, that's probably your first mistake. =)

Answer (score 1):

Browsers have an option to copy the URL of a link to the clipboard. Right-click / long-click on the link, and click on the copy option, something like:

- `Copy shortcut` (Internet Explorer)
- `Copy Link Location` (Mozilla Firefox)
- `Copy link address` (Google Chrome)

Then you can paste it into prompt where you're running `wget`.

By "server function call" I assume you mean that the URL has parameters at the end, e.g. `?foo=bar&baz=bat`.  That's nothing special from `wget`'s point of view, although be aware that most shells have special meanings for `&`s; to put a literal `&` through to the command you need to escape it with `\` or put it in quotes (for simplicity you can just put the whole URL in quotes).

Some versions of `wget` let you use the filename suggested by the server, by passing the option `--content-disposition`.

```
wget --content-disposition 'http://www.somesite.com/path/to/something?foo=bar&baz=bat'
```

Comment: Note that if the server uses some mechanism to limit access to the URL, such as cookies, a client-side certificate, or a special header in the request, `wget` will also have to provide that value in its request to download the URL.  You will need to figure out the value you need and then use the appropriate parameters of `wget` to pass it, if possible.